# My Bootstrap Alert does not show up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why the alert doesn't show up when clicked?

I have these HTML:

```
<div id="submit-errors" class="alert alert-error fade in">
    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
     <h4 class="alert-heading">Errors</h4>
    <p>sdfgsdg</p>
</div>
<button id='foo'>foo</button>
```

and JS Scripts:

```
$('#submit-errors').alert('close');
$('#foo').on('click', function () {
    $('#submit-errors').alert('open');
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XKYeg/1/

Comment: Is there such a thing as `alert('open')`?  I thought the twitter bootstrap `alert` functionality is only to allow the dismissal of an alert box.

Comment: I guess not. So there's no way to bring it up again after it's dismissed?

Comment: Nope, it's a one way street. :)  You dismiss it, it's gone.

Comment: I hope there's a different answer. but Thanks!

Comment: For a different approach (not using `alert()`), see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this alert to be toggle-able, you might not want to use the `alert()` method at all.  But you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="submit-errors" class="alert alert-error hide">
    <button id="closeAlert" class="close" type="button"></button>
    <h4 class="alert-heading">Errors</h4>
    <p>sdfgsdg</p>
</div>
<button id='foo'>foo</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function () {
    $('#submit-errors').show();
});

$('#closeAlert').on('click', function () {
    $('#submit-errors').hide();
});
```

Comment: I was going to this direction too with `addClass('hide')` and `'removeClass('hide')`, but i think plain `hide` and `show` is better.

Comment: @dplass - Why would this no longer work wit BS3?  This answer isn't even relying on BS, besides the styling.  If you look correctly, all I am doing here is using jQuery to show/hide the box.

Comment: I don't know. But putting the "hide" class in the div makes it un-show-able. I had to leave the "hide" off, and call hide() in JS on my page, for it to be showable/hideable.

Answer (score 1):

If you never call : `$('#submit-errors').alert('close');`

You could do this:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function () {
    $('#submit-errors').toggleClass('out, in');
});
```

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XKYeg/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/XKYeg/3/)

Answer (score 0):

as there is no such thing call open is bootstrap alert... the way around is.... `hide()` it first and `show()` it on click

```
$('#submit-errors').hide();
$('#foo').on('click', function () {
    console.log('here');
    $('#submit-errors').show(); //or slideDown() for effect
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XKYeg/5/)

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to reference this:

```
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I had same problem. I added it, and it worked.